# Xamarin displayalert not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, xamarin.forms, signalr

I have **xamarin** form application and i connected it **signalr** not running my void. I searched on internet but I can't find anything about this. And  this is my code
**Myhub.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;

namespace PharmClient
{
    class MyHub
    {
        string url = "https://webapplication11-co5.conveyor.cloud/";
        HubConnection Connection;
        IHubProxy ProxyOFServer;
        public delegate void Error();
        public delegate void MessageRecieved(string _data);
        public event Error CoonectionError;
        public event MessageRecieved OndataRecieved;
        public delegate void Completed();
        public event Completed OnCompleted;

        public void Connect()
        {
            Connection = new HubConnection(url);
            ProxyOFServer = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MuHub");
            Start().ContinueWith(task => { if (task.IsFaulted) { CoonectionError?.Invoke(); } else { OnCompleted?.Invoke(); }  });

        }

        public Task Start()
        {
            return Connection.Start();
        }
        public void SendData(string data)
        {
            ProxyOFServer.Invoke<string>("SendMessage", data);
        }

        public void Recive( )
        {
            ProxyOFServer.On<string>("Sentdata", data => { OndataRecieved?.Invoke(data); });
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Threading;
namespace PharmClient
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        MyHub ConnectServer = new MyHub();
        public  MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            ConnectServer.OnCompleted += ConnectServer_OnCompleted;
            ConnectServer.CoonectionError += ConnectServer_CoonectionError;

             ConnectServer.Connect();
        }

        private void ConnectServer_OnCompleted()
        {
            DisplayAlert("Connected", "Good", "O");
        }

        private void ConnectServer_CoonectionError()
        {
            DisplayAlert("Failed", "Bad", "Ok");
        }

        private void SerchDrug_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new SearchDrug());
        }
    }
}
```

When connection failed **ConnectionError** event run but Connection will be successfully **OnCompleted** event won't run. I am student. This is part of group work. What is problem my code any Help. I can't found anything. Thanks for attention

Comment: its soo confusing. what actually do you want to ask?

Answer (score 1):

As your title suggest, you have an issue with displaying a dialog box.

Try going through the documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups)) once for complete understanding, you have to `await` the process of displaying `DisplayAlert`.

Add `await` & `async` to your methods.

Try this -

```
        private async void ConnectServer_OnCompleted()
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Connected", "Good", "O");
        }

        private async void ConnectServer_CoonectionError()
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Failed", "Bad", "Ok");
        }
```

If you have some issues regarding, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should await connection not fire and forget. Example:

```
    private HubConnection connection;
    private IHubProxy proxy;
    public event EventHandler<ChatMessageObject> OnMessageReceived;

    public async Task Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            await connection.Start();

            await proxy.Invoke("Connect"); // example method in your backend

            proxy.On("messageReceived", (int userId, string name, string message, DateTime messageDateTime) => OnMessageReceived(this, new ChatMessageObject
            {
                FromUserId = userId,
                UserName = name,
                MessageText = message,
                MessageDateTime = messageDateTime
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exceptions
        }
    }
```